# Working with multiple sockets in one thread using ZeroMQ.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, zeromq

I am trying to implement a service using `ZeroMQ` and `Node.js`. 
I am using [the ZeroMQ.js bindings](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/) for it. [The ZeroMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:chapter2#Handling-Multiple-Sockets) shows how to process multiple sockets in one thread: using the [zmq_poller](http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-poller).
I am trying to implement something similar in Node.js but I can not find a good way how to do this. 
I tried using [Promise.race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) like so:

```
while(true) {
  const message = await Promise.race([socket1.receive(), socket2.receive()]);
  // process message, start over again
}
```

But this throws an error when entering the while-loop for the second time since the socket that was slower in the first iteration is already in receive mode.
Calling `receive()` on it a second time will result in an error.
So my question is: Is there a way to mimic `zmq_poller` with ZeroMQ.js or is there another sensible way to handle multiple sockets. 
I want to avoid forking since the use cases I am trying to implement require me to use multiple sockets for one use case.

Comment: Have you checked in the underlying zeromq.js library if you need to do this? You (hopefully) shouldn't need to worry about a low level thread implementation detail like this in a higher level js library (unless the library was a 1to1 mapping of the C api)

Comment: e.g would two async loops do

Comment: I don't know what that would work look like, would you kindly provide a code snippet for what you are meaning? Awaiting one `receive()` call before the other would meant the second `receive()` is only called once the first one resolves. This would mean I would not receive any messages for the second slot unless I get a message on the first socket first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to read two sockets without any synchronisation then two asyncronous loops that await data may help:

```
async function sub(){
  const sock = new zmq.Subscriber
  sock.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:3000')
  sock.subscribe('rabbits')
  for await (const [topic, msg] of sock) {
    console.log('received [%s]', topic, msg)
  }
}

async function pull(){
  const sock = new zmq.Pull
  sock.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:3001')
  for await (const [msg] of sock) {
    console.log('pulled', msg)
  }
}

pull().catch(e => {console.error(e); process.exit(1)})
sub().catch(e => {console.error(e); process.exit(1)})
console.log('waiting for data')
```

The `await` on the zeromq socket is a non blocking operation so the JS event loop continues on. Don't worry about the lower level thread implementation.